# SwipeRefreshLayout Refresh Listener not calling onRefresh()

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

I currently have a SwipeRefreshLayout that isn't calling its OnRefresh method whenever I pull down. Is something wrong with my code?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe_view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    swipe_view = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.this_will_work);

    swipe_view.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh()
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OnRefresh() test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a service or something that will be updated like below :

```
private void refresh() {
    startService(new Intent(this, UpdaterService.class));
}
```

then Refresh :

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                    refresh();
                                }});

//here refreshed Item
   //getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        refresh();
    }
```

and your `onRefresh()` should contain the same method `refresh()`.

Comment: `this` throws an error saying: `Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'my.app.name.MainActivity', required: 'android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<java.lang.Object>'`

Comment: you may hash this line if you are not using onLoadFinish `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);`

Comment: Still, whenever I am pulling down to refresh none of my methods are called. Also `setColorSchemeResources()` doesn't change colors when called, so at this point, I think something is broken with my app.  +1 Though for trying to help me

Comment: you should put your refreshed item instead of comment i wrote, and if you are retrieve data online or some thing the updaterservice will update it.

Comment: I did, I replaced the refresh() methods with my own.

Comment: above this line put your refreshed item `if (savedInstanceState == null)`

Comment: Still, none of the methods are called. I think this is a problem with something else I'm having. \: